# Ascending Sort of Float Dictionary Values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form:

`d = { 'someText': floatNumber }`

Where `floatNumber` is an epoch timestamp. I'm trying to organise this such that time is in ascending order.

Example: `{'someText':0000001, 'someText1':0000002, and so on}`

Only way I can think of doing it is by looping with `for k,v in dict.items()` and then manually sorting it into a list but that may take a long time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `['someText':0000001, ...]`? What is that supposed to be, a list?

Comment: Don't use the reserved word `dict` as a variable.

Comment: But the `[k1:v1, k2:v2, ...]` syntax is neither a list nor a dictionary.

Comment: Look at: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and you'll see: `tel['irv'] = 4127` ->  `tel` -> `{'guido': 4127, 'irv': 4127, 'jack': 4098}` -> My format.

Comment: No, you use `[` in the line starting with 'Example', not `{`.

Comment: Well since it was a question and that format was an example of output, then it could have been a dictionary or a list or anything you wanted. Nonetheless it's edited, for you.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you with your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
import operator
values = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

which would generate a sorted list of tuples, like

```
[('someText', 1), ('someText', 2), ...]
```

Dictionaries cannot be sorted, so you have to use another data structure to store your key-value pairs.

Comment: Did the job perfectly. May I ask why `1` is passed into `itemgetter()`?

Comment: @malcmcmul: Every element of `d.items()` is a tuple, containing the key as first and the value as second element. Indexes of lists and tuples are 0-based. Hence the index of the value in the tuple (by which you want to sort) is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

An [order dictionary](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) can be used to store the entries in sorted order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'foo':1, 'bar':3, 'baz':2}
l = [(k, v) for k, v in d.items()]
s = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))

# s == [('foo', 1), ('baz', 2), ('bar', 3)]
```

More on sorting: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

**Edit:**

Improved version (thanks for the comment):

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'foo':1, 'bar':3, 'baz':2}
s = sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))

# s == [('foo', 1), ('baz', 2), ('bar', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, by default dictionaries are unsorted. You may want to use a list and insert into the appropriate location as you build the dataset. Otherwise, use the `sorted` function.

```
sorted(dict.iteritems(), key=lambda (x, y): y)
```